# How do I enable nvidia-persistenced.service?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, systemd, cuda

I'm trying to install CUDA on my Ubuntu Budgie 17.10, with a GTX 1060. I'm stuck on this part of the instructions:

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#power9-setup

I've pasted the example into the specified file. When I try to run

```
sudo systemctl enable nvidia-persistenced
```

I get:

```
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).
This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
4) In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
   instance name specified.
```

For reference, here's the exact content of my file:

```
[Unit] 
Description=NVIDIA Persistence Daemon
Wants=syslog.target 

[Service] 
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/nvidia-persistenced/nvidia-persistenced.pid
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --verbose
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -rf /var/run/nvidia persistenced 

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I don't know anything about these files, which is why I'm just copying and pasting - so I'd be happy if you could tell me what's wrong!

Comment: It is required by the nvidia service you installed earlier so run `systemctl list-units | grep nvidia` lets get the name of the service then add the line `RequiredBy=<name-of-nvidia-service>`, example `RequiredBy=nvidia.service` to the `[Install]` section and try that command again!

Comment: If I grep nvidia I only find the process that I'm trying to enable (nvidia-persistenced.service) and interestingly enough it's marked as loaded active running. And yet even if I add the RequiredBy and try to enable it I still get the error message... But Thanks for the Hint!

Comment: What other nvidia service is seen in that query?

Comment: None, just that one...

Comment: If that is the case then don't use that as a requirement in the install section!

Comment: Try `RequiredBy=default.target` and stop, disable, add that line then re-enable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be a little late, but I hope this helps others with this.

From what I understand, you do NOT have a POWER9 system, not unless your system is a supercomputer.

According to this [link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1035540/cuda-setup-and-installation/1050-ti-laptop-cuda-9-2-nvidia-persistenced-problems/) and [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POWER9).

Being a Linux rookie, I too was stuck on this for a long time.

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to reload systemd manager configuration first after making changes.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Then you can try to enable/start the service.