# Issue with Ubuntu 18.04 and CUDA 9.1

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, cuda

I follow the instruction in [https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#mandatory-post](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#pre-installation-actions).
At the step "2.6. Download the NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit", there is not a option of Ubuntu 18.04, so I choose Ubuntu 17.04.
But at the step "7.1.2. POWER9 Setup", I create the service file as example but I find at the path

> /var/run/nvidia-persistenced

there is not a PIDFile named

> nvidia-persistenced.pid

after I run the command:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable nvidia-persistenced
```

terminal shows:

```
    The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).
This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
4) In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
   instance name specified.
```

In addition, there also another error about nvidia. When I try to run
`$ nvidia-` or `$ nvidia-smi`, always shows *`no command`* and *`NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.`*

I think I install CUDA and CUDA-drivers correctly because there is not error showed when i install both of them. **So i think maybe there are something wrong about nvidia-persistenced.**

I have read another Questions [How do I enable nvidia-persistenced.service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022946/how-do-i-enable-nvidia-persistenced-service), but it seems it does not solve it.

Comment: The cuda 9.1 is now in the 18.04 official repositories and installs with `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`.  For the NVIDIA drivers themselves, best to install them from the `graphics-drivers` ppa.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers  and it still works with Ubuntu 18.04 and you can install the `nvidia-driver-396` as the newest driver.

Comment: If you get a stuck, I did write an answer last night, but updated it this evening and it should work fine:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1030901/231142